# Determine a user's reputation on a given day

Tags: support, reputation

It's easy to tell how much reputation a user has.  And it's easy to tell how much reputation they made on a given day.  But recently, there have been a few cases where I have wanted to determine a given user's *total reputation* on a particular day.

Is there a way to do this?  Can I determine how much total reputation a given user had on a particular day, say, on September 12, 2014?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see any users reputation on specific days (from all of their accounts) on the network profile reputation graph. This is yours for example:

> [image]

You can zoom in on an area of the graph by dragging a selection over that area to make it easier to select a specific date:

> [image]