# SEDE query to find users' reputation when posting their questions

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, data-dump

Each question has an Id, OwnerUserId, and CreationDate. I need to calculate the reputation of that user (questioner) was during the question creation time. I find the question ([Determining user's reputation as of particular date?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313561/determining-users-reputation-as-of-particular-date)
) and SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882556/reputation-gained-until-a-certain-date) much helpful but it requires user input. The total number of questions is pretty large so I need to avoid the user input and make a general query. I am trying to modify the query but failed. In particular, I require the records in the following manner:

Question Id -- CreationDate --- OwnerUserId -- Reputation (on CreationDate)

Comment: Could you please explain why negative vote? I described why I ask this question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you haven't really shown what you've tried. Such questions are (rightfully) met with down- and close votes on sites like Stack Overflow and Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1061357/reputation-when-posting-a-question) might be a good start. The query comes with the caveat that calculating reputation via SEDE is unreliable; reputation subtracted from *casting* downvotes on answer isn't taken into account, and neither is the 'timing' from votes when you hit the reputation cap. Also, this particular query reports the reputation at the end of the previous day (since if it's a good question, it's bound to give you reputation on the day itself already).

These are my questions on Stack Overflow and the reputation I approximately had when asking them:

[image]

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I've updated the query, it should perform much better now. It even works on my own Meta.SE account.

Comment: Better. And it even works for Jon Skeet (but he only has 50 questions).